# Difference between 'crow's feet' and 'worry lines'

Tags: etymology, differences

I came across the phrases 'crow's feet' and 'worry lines' several times. Please enlighten me about the origin of these two phrases and the difference between them.

Answer (score 7):

According to the Random House Dictionary, [crow's feet](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/crow%27s-foot) originated sometime between 1350–1400. The phrase refers to wrinkles on the outer corner of the eye, like a crow's foot or footprint, as opposed to [worry lines](http://www.dermnetnz.org/site-age-specific/wrinkles.html)--wrinkles on the forehead.

Answer (score 3):

According to the online blog, *fandom grammar*, the origin of crow's feet can be traced back to the 1300s

> “The most commonly used definition of **[crow's feet](http://fandom-grammar.livejournal.com/85104.html)** is tiny wrinkles at the outer corner of the eyes, resulting from age or constant squinting” and are so called because of the likeness to a crow’s foot or footprint.  It originates in the late 14th century from Middle English and is believed **to have first appeared in print in Chaucer’s poem “Troilus and Criseyde.”**
>   The phrase in the singular is **crow’s-foot**, but it is most often used in the plural, as in crow’s-feet.
>
> It can also mean **“an embroidery stitch with three points, used as a finish at the end of a seam or opening,”** or **“an arrangement of ropes in which one main rope exerts pull at several points simultaneously through a group of smaller ropes, as in balloon or airship rigging.”**   These other definitions are much less frequently used, and when they are, it is usually in the singular crow’s-foot.

**[Worry lines](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Worry%20lines,%20worry%20lines&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,Worry%20lines;,c0;.t1;,worry%20lines;,c0)**
[*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worry%20line) defines it as “a crease or wrinkle on the forehead or between the eyebrows” (while crow's feet develop at the outer corners of the eyes).

This expression has been used since the beginning of last century but has become popular since the 1960's probably with the development of the beauty industry.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement @Sel and Josh61's answers.

For some reason, the highly unflattery term, *crow's feet* are wrinkles normally associated with women. The tiny fan-like lines at the outer corners of eyes occur over time when a person repeatedly squints or laughs, in fact a more complimentary term to describe the marked lines on someone's face would be *laughter lines* or *character lines*.

[image: crow's feet]  [image]

On the other hand, *[worry lines](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worry?show=2&t=1407393700)* are caused by the repeated raising of eyebrows which in turn lead to the furrowing of the forehead, they are said to represent the expressions of worry and concern. The term is used indifferently between men and women and according to Merriam & Webster it was first used in 1972.

EDIT

One of the first written instances of *worry lines* I found online which contradicts with the M&W claim is in the book titled:  *[Are We All Deceivers?](https://archive.org/details/arewealldeceive00leslgoog): The Lover's Blue Book* (1896)
[image]

Comment: Didn't know about laughter lines or character lines...thanks!

Comment: Do you have any evidence for "crow's feet are normally associated with women". My feeling is that it's just that women on average worry about them more.

Comment: @Rupe The evidence I have is my personal experience, and it is true on average  that women are more concerned about their skin's appearance than men are. Women's skins tend to be frailer and thinner then men's, hence more prone to lines. Note too the snippet which I posted.

Answer (score -2):

The crow is linked to Cronos, the God of time and harvest. Where we get  chronology. So the association between showing aging lines being crows feet.

From Wikipedia
Robert Graves remarks that "cronos probably means 'crow', like the Latin cornix and the Greek corōne", noting that Cronus was depicted with a crow, as were the deities Apollo, Asclepius, Saturn and Bran.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronus

The crow symbol is associated with death. Death the character is old man time. Crow is linked to Cronos or Kronos. Also linked to chronology or time. Being the farthest planet visible from earth by the nakid eye. It can blind you to look at it or so its said. Pay too close attention to time and before you know it your time is up. And you end up with crows feet or worry lines.

it's thought by most in ancient times to be the measure of time by which the rest must work to move their heavenly bodies around the firmament.

Comment: Can you provide references? Answers without references will often get deleted.

Comment: Are you saying "crow" is etymologically linked to "Cronos"? (It isn't, not even remotely.) You need to support your statements; otherwise, your answer will likely get deleted as utter balderdash.

Comment: Yes I am saying that. Taken from Wikipedia. "Robert Graves remarks that "cronos probably means 'crow', like the Latin cornix and the Greek corōne", noting that Cronus was depicted with a crow, as were the deities Apollo, Asclepius, Saturn and Bran.". Also Zeus and Oden. Probably many others depicted with a crow and associated with time. Mainly time to harvest.